# Dozer mapping Booleans

Tags: java, dozer

I am using dozer and I can't map from boolean to Boolean. What could be the problem?

mapping xhtml

```
<field>
    <a>test</a>
    <b is-accessible="true" >test2</b>
</field>
```

class a

```
private boolean test;

public boolean getTest(){
    return test;
}
```

class b

```
private Boolean test2;

public boolean isTest2(){
    return test2;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What error do you get?

Comment: `get...()` vs. `is...()` - I recall Dozer being picky about that...

Comment: The problem is that after mapping object is filled without the test2 field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dozer 5.4.0, the following worked for me

```
    <field>
        <a is-accessible="true" get-method="isFoo">foo</a>
        <b is-accessible="true" set-method="setFoo">foo</b>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/simpleproperty.html) on Dozer, this should be possible:

> Data type coversion is performed automatically by the Dozer mapping engine. Currently, Dozer supports the following types of conversions: (these are all bi-directional)
>
> - Primitive to Primitive Wrapper
> - ...

You can try if [specifying set-method and get-method helps](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/custommethods.html).

Comment: I tried some combinations with get-methods, set-methods also, and its still not working. Where should i place get-method where set-method?

Comment: I have executed your code with Dozer 5.4.0 and it is working fine, even without set-method or get-method specified. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using it in test with deepEqual: ERROR main (...deepEquals.DeepEquals:154): ... #test2:java.lang.Boolean field are not equal (true!=null)|#]

Comment: Can you also add all the code that you already have to your question?

Comment: Theres noting to add i think. I just make some test of mapping for two objects. Diffrence with thoose 2 object is that one have field boolean other Boolean like i wrote in question, thats all. Thats really wird